# ２つファイルのCSVデータ比較について【重複・行の追加・空白】

Tags: python, csv

やりたいこと
2つのcsvファイルを比較して、両ファイル内の差分を抽出し、別のファイルにデータを書き込みたいです。
下記のコードのように条件を指定して差分を抽出したいですが途中で行の追加と空白・Noの重複がありますので、
希望通りの出力結果にならないです。

**csvデータ① (カンマ区切り)**

```
No,テスト1,テスト日,New／Existing,テスト名,テスト数,テスト担当,テスト訪問日,テスト名,テスト2,テストフラグ,テスト3,テスト4,テスト5,テスト6,テスト7,テスト8,テスト9,テスト10,テスト11,テスト12,テスト13,テスト14,テスト15,テスト16,テスト17,テスト18,テスト19,テスト20,テスト21,テスト21,テスト22,テスト23,"テスト24
500","テスト25
700","テスト26
200","テスト27
220","テスト28
100",テスト29,テスト30,テスト31,テスト32,テスト33,テスト34,テスト35,テスト36,,,
51,コム,2021/02/26,New,会社A,20,テストA,2021/02/09,テストA,担当者,OK,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,2021/02/01,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2021/02/26,Existing,会社B,,,2021/02/26,テストA,担当者,OK,,2,2,,,,,,2,,,,2021/02/01,,2,卸売・小売業,,,2,,,163734,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2021/02/26,Existing,会社C,,テストA,2021/02/26,テストA,担当者,OK,,9,9,,,,,,9,,,,2021/02/01,,9,サービス業,9,,,,,346932,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2021/02/26,New,会社D,,テストA,2021/02/26,テストA,担当者,NG,,3,,,3,,,,0.9,,,,2021/02/01,,3,建設業,3,,,,,77394,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11,コム,2020/04/01,New,会社D,2,テストA,2020/03/10,テストA,代表,NG,テスト,0,,,,,,,0,,,,2020/04/01,,0,"建設業
",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1234,1234,1234
51,コム,2021/03/01,,会社E,48,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,担当者,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,2021/03/01,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
52,コム,2021/03/01,,会社F,1,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,担当者,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,2021/03/01,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,1,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,3,4,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,1,2,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,4,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

**csvデータ② (カンマ区切り)**

```
No,テスト1,テスト日,New／Existing,テスト名,テスト数,テスト担当,テスト訪問日,テスト名,テスト2,テストフラグ,テスト3,テスト4,テスト5,テスト6,テスト7,テスト8,テスト9,テスト10,テスト11,テスト12,テスト13,テスト14,テスト15,テスト16,テスト17,テスト18,テスト19,テスト20,テスト21,テスト21,テスト22,テスト23,"テスト24
500","テスト25
700","テスト26
200","テスト27
220","テスト28
100",テスト29,テスト30,テスト31,テスト32,テスト33,テスト34,テスト35,テスト36,,,
51,コム,2021/02/26,New,会社A,20,テストA,2021/02/09,テストA,担当者,OK,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,2021/02/01,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2021/02/26,Existing,会社B,,,2021/02/26,テストA,担当者,OK,,2,2,,,,,,2,,,,2021/02/01,,2,卸売・小売業,,,2,,,163734,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2021/02/26,Existing,会社C,,テストA,2021/02/26,テストA,担当者,OK,,9,9,,,,,,9,,,,2021/02/01,,9,サービス業,9,,,,,346932,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
50,コム,2021/03/01,,会社E,48,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,担当者,NG,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,2021/03/01,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2021/02/26,New,会社D,,テストA,2021/02/26,テストA,担当者,OK,,3,,,3,,,,0.9,,,,2021/02/01,,3,建設業,3,,,,,77394,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11,コム,2020/04/01,New,会社D,2,テストA,2020/03/10,テストA,代表,OK,テスト,0,,,,,,,0,,,,2020/04/01,,0,"建設業
",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1234,1234,1234
51,コム,2021/03/02,,会社E,49,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,担当者,□,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,2021/03/01,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
52,コム,2021/03/01,,会社F,1,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,担当者,△,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,2021/03/01,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
91,コム,2021/03/01,,会社G,1,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,代表,OK,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,2021/03/01,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
57,コム,2021/03/02,,会社H,1,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,担当者,NG,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,2021/03/01,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,0,,,,#NUM!,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,1,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,3,4,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,1,2,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,4,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

現在の差分出力内容

```
No,テスト1,テスト日,New／Existing,テスト名,テスト数,テスト担当,テスト訪問日,テスト名.1,テスト2,テストフラグ,テスト3,テスト4,テスト5,テスト6,テスト7,テスト8,テスト9,テスト10,テスト11,テスト12,テスト13,テスト14,テスト15,テスト16,テスト17,テスト18,テスト19,テスト20,テスト21,テスト21.1,テスト22,テスト23,"テスト24
500","テスト25
700","テスト26
200","テスト27
220","テスト28
100",テスト29,テスト30,テスト31,テスト32,テスト33,テスト34,テスト35,テスト36,Unnamed: 46,Unnamed: 47,Unnamed: 48
51.0,コム,2021/02/26,New,会社A,20.0,テストA,2021/02/09,テストA,担当者,OK,,0.0,,,,,,,0.0,,,,2021/02/01,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2021/02/26,Existing,会社B,,,2021/02/26,テストA,担当者,OK,,2.0,2.0,,,,,,2.0,,,,2021/02/01,,2.0,卸売・小売業,,,2.0,,,163734.0,,,2.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2021/02/26,Existing,会社C,,テストA,2021/02/26,テストA,担当者,OK,,9.0,9.0,,,,,,9.0,,,,2021/02/01,,9.0,サービス業,9.0,,,,,346932.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
50.0,コム,2021/03/01,,会社E,48.0,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,担当者,NG,,0.0,,,,,,,0.0,,,,2021/03/01,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2021/02/26,New,会社D,,テストA,2021/02/26,テストA,担当者,OK,,3.0,,,3.0,,,,0.9,,,,2021/02/01,,3.0,建設業,3.0,,,,,77394.0,3.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11.0,コム,2020/04/01,New,会社D,2.0,テストA,2020/03/10,テストA,代表,OK,テスト,0.0,,,,,,,0.0,,,,2020/04/01,,0.0,"建設業
",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1234.0,1234.0,1234.0
91.0,コム,2021/03/01,,会社G,1.0,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,代表,OK,,0.0,,,,,,,0.0,,,,2021/03/01,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
57.0,コム,2021/03/02,,会社H,1.0,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,担当者,NG,,0.0,,,,,,,0.0,,,,2021/03/01,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

```
CSV②の方は途中と最後で行を追加しました。
また、カラムのテストフラグのステータス例：No11をNG→OKに変更しております。

差分のデータを出力されますが、変換していない部分も拾ってしまいます。
例えばNo51と空白があるNoを拾ってしまします。
原因は空白でしょうか。
```

出力希望結果

```
No,テスト1,テスト日,New／Existing,テスト名,テスト数,テスト担当,テスト訪問日,テスト名.1,テスト2,テストフラグ,テスト3,テスト4,テスト5,テスト6,テスト7,テスト8,テスト9,テスト10,テスト11,テスト12,テスト13,テスト14,テスト15,テスト16,テスト17,テスト18,テスト19,テスト20,テスト21,テスト21.1,テスト22,テスト23,"テスト24
500","テスト25
700","テスト26
200","テスト27
220","テスト28
100",テスト29,テスト30,テスト31,テスト32,テスト33,テスト34,テスト35,テスト36,Unnamed: 46,Unnamed: 47,Unnamed: 48
50.0,コム,2021/03/01,,会社E,48.0,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,担当者,NG,,0.0,,,,,,,0.0,,,,2021/03/01,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,2021/02/26,New,会社D,,テストA,2021/02/26,テストA,担当者,OK,,3.0,,,3.0,,,,0.9,,,,2021/02/01,,3.0,建設業,3.0,,,,,77394.0,3.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
91.0,コム,2021/03/01,,会社G,1.0,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,代表,OK,,0.0,,,,,,,0.0,,,,2021/03/01,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
57.0,コム,2021/03/02,,会社H,1.0,テストA,2021/02/25,テストA,担当者,NG,,0.0,,,,,,,0.0,,,,2021/03/01,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

現在のコード
条件
tuple に変換してからCSVファイル①、CSVファイル❷の差分を取得を行います。
その後にOKとNGだけの特定の文字が変換もしくは行を追加されたらデータを取得します。

```
import pandas as pd

#差分抽出方法のコード

#ファイルの読み込み
df1 = pd.read_csv("20210228.csv",encoding='utf_8_sig')
print(df1)
df2 = pd.read_csv("20210301.csv",encoding='utf_8_sig')

# tuple に変換してから差分を取得
df3 = df2[~df2.apply(tuple,1).isin(df1.apply(tuple,1))]

#特定の文字を検索
df_h = df3[df3["テストフラグ"].str.contains("OK|NG",na=False)].reset_index(drop=True)

#ファイル書き込み
df_h.to_csv("test.csv", encoding='utf_8_sig', index=False)

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
print(df_h)
```

変換していない部分を拾えないようにするためにどのようにすれば、よろしいでしょうか。

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: `float('nan') == float('nan')` は `False` になりますので、`read_csv` に `keep_default_na=False` を追加して下さい。`df1 = pd.read_csv("20210228.csv", keep_default_na=False, encoding='utf_8_sig')`(df2 も同様)

Comment: @metropolis 
いつも回答ありがとうございます。上記の方法で差分の行数が減りました。ただ気づいたことは`df2のcsvファイルのカラムテスト日`の日付を変更するとそのデータも差分として拾ってしまいます。`テストフラグ`が変化した時だけ拾うことができないでしょうか。お手数ですが、ご確認をお願い致します。

Comment: `dtype=str`も入れてみましたが`テスト日`の日付だけを変更するとそのデータも差分とし拾ってしまいます。。

Comment: 全てのカラムを比較していますのでそうなります。比較対象から「テスト日」を除外する場合は、`df3 = df2[~df2.drop(['テスト日'], axis=1).apply(tuple,1).isin(df1.drop(['テスト日'], axis=1).apply(tuple,1))]` とします。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。早速特定のカラムだけを比較するように指定しましたらこちらのデータで上手く差分出力できましたが、実際のデータだとテストフラグが変化していないのに一部の差分として拾ってしまいます。理由分かりますでしょうか。変更した部分です。
`df3 = df2[~df2.apply(tuple,1,'テストフラグ).isin(df1.apply(tuple,1,'テストフラグ))]`

Comment: 失礼しました。上記のコメント気づきませんでした。そちらも確認してみます。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: 比較対象から'テストフラグ'が変換した時だけ差分したいので、テストフラグを除いて複数のカラムを記載しましたが、出力結果何も表示されないです。
`df3 = df2[~df2.drop(['No','テスト1','テスト日','New／Existing'...], axis=1).apply(tuple,1).isin(df1.drop(['No','テスト1','テスト日','New／Existing...'], axis=1).apply(tuple,1))]`

Comment: @metropolis 
上記の方法で間違えしていましたら、すいませんが教えていただけますか。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: `No` を削ってしまったら比較にならないと思いますが…

Comment: @metropolis なるほどですね、Noを比較対象から抜けましたら、上手く差分出力できました。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: 度々、すいません
カラム数が多いため、index_colを使ってカラムの範囲を指定して比較したいのですがSyntaxErrorと表示されます。`df3 =df2[~df2.drop.iloc([1:9,11:48],axis=1).apply(tuple,1).isin(df1.drop.iloc([1:9,11:48],axis=1).apply(tuple,1))]`

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax　.iloc([1:9,11:48]`.ilocを入れてみましたが、ダメでした。もしこちらも分かりましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: そこまで削るのでしたら逆に考えてみてはどうでしょうか。まず、`cols = ['No', 'テストフラグ']` としておいて、`df3 = df2[~df2[cols].apply(tuple,1).isin(df1[cols].apply(tuple,1))]` とします。

Comment: @metropolis なるほどですね、isinを使って「'No', 'テストフラグ'」が含んでいるものを確認してからtuppleに変換しますね。助かりました。ありがとうございます